# Debug protractor test in visual studio code(VS code)

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, protractor, visual-studio-code

I want to debug my protractor project built in **Javascript** and **nodeJS** with open source **IDE**. As I have already tried with this(**VS Code**), but it is unable to proceed further as there is no "sync" between browser and code.
Can any one please suggest any solution for this or rather any better alternative to this.

Note that I have already tried my luck with :

1.) **Webstorm** - Can't use because it is a licensed and not allowed in our Organization

2.)**elementExplorer** - used only for locating elements in interactive mode.

3.) **Netbeans** - Not supported debugging.

4.) **Eclipse with nodeclipse and Webclips**e- Not much effective to debug.

5.) **Apatana Studio 3.0** - cannot use existing javascript & nodeJS projects .

Kindly help me out . Better solutions are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

in command line run following command:  webdriver-manager start

launch.json file is below

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "c:/Users/yourUserName/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
      "args": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/conf.js"
      ],
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": null,
      "runtimeExecutable": null,
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--nolazy"
      ],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "externalConsole": false,
      "sourceMaps": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Attach",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 5858,
      "address": "localhost",
      "restart": false,
      "sourceMaps": false,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "remoteRoot": null
    },
    {
      "name": "launch",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "processId": "${command.PickProcess}",
      "port": 5858,
      "sourceMaps": false,
      "outDir": null
    }
  ]
}
```